# Jquery working with literal value, but not my PHP returned JSON data from $.post

Tags: jquery, json

I'm using jQuery's $.post to get values from a query and (trying to) populate a form with those values. The populate plugin needs a JSON object. To test my success callback, I alert and display the data - which looks like valid JSON to me, but the plugin doesn't load the form field. However, if I substitute a literal value e.g. {"cust_id": "65"}, it works. 
What's the issue? 
Thanks.

.....here's the client side:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(".button").click(function () {        

      var suite = $("input#suite_no").val();

      $.post("get_custrec.php",
        { suite_no: suite },
        function(data){
           data = data.substring(1, data.length-1);
           $('#output').html(data);
           alert("Data: " + data);
           $('#custForm').populate(data);
         }
       );
       return false;
    });
    </script>
```

.......my server (php) code:

```
  $result = mysql_query($sql);

  $arr = array();
  while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $arr[] = $obj;
  }
  echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: show the populate() function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post("get_custrec.php",
    { suite_no: suite },
    function(data){
       data = data.substring(1, data.length-1);
       $('#output').html(data);
       alert("Data: " + data);
       $('#custForm').populate(data);
     }, 'json' //just need to add this ;)
   );
```

Comment: Thank for your answers. I tried adding 'json' but the output and alert functions don't display. How would I set the HHTP header?$(".button").click(function () {  
     
  var suite = $("input#suite_no").val();
      alert("Suite: " + suite);
  $.post("get_custrec.php",
   { suite_no: suite},
     function(data){
      //var newdata = new String(data);
      //data = data.toString().substring(1, data.length-1);
   $('#output').html(data);
   alert("Data: " + data);
      $('#custForm').populate(data);
   
    }, 'json'
 );
   return false;
   });

Comment: first off - if you're receiving data back as json, get that substring out of there. It won't work and is useless.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion and sorry it's taken me so long to get back and see it... but the reason I substring is the returned data from json_encode comes back enclosed in brackets, like so [{"cust_id": "65"}]. I'll recheck this.

Comment: well json is not a string, it is an object.. so you want to do data = data[0], the first element in the array. [] is a javascript array.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify the [`dataType`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) that will be returned, jQuery tries to guess it by looking at the response's MIME type (e.g. the HTTP `Content-Type` header). Since it doesn't look like you're setting the header, you need to:

- set the correct HTTP header: `header("Content-Type: application/json");` **and/or**
- tell jQuery what the dataType is, with one more argument to [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/):

  `$.post('get_custrec.php', {...}, function (data) {...}, 'json')`

Either one will suffice; using both will not hurt.